# Test of Independence: Combinatorics for P-values?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I feel bad for posting a whole question, but I'm really stuck on it, and would appreciate anything even a hint to it!
I'll show what I tried at the bottom.

## Question

A test is used to determine if a sequence of binary numbers are independent, by counting the number of times $X$ that there is a change in response between consecutive trials in the sequence (from failure to success and vice versa).
As an example, a sequence (let $S$ denote success and $F$ denote failure) is
$$S \ S \ F \ S \ F \ S \ F \ S \ S \ F.$$

This sequence has $X = 7$ changes.

$(i)$ Assume this test is an unconditional test, with some known probaility $p = 0.5$ where $n$ is the number of trials.
Explain why $X \sim Bin(n-1,0.5)$.
$(ii)$ Consider the 3 sequences:
$$(A): \ \ \ F \ F \ S \ S \ S \ S \ S \ F \ F \ S \\ (B): \ \ \ S \ S \ F \ S \ F \ S \ F \ S \ S \ F \\ (C): \ \ \ S \ S \ S \ F \ S \ F \ S \ S \ F \ F.$$

Which test is the least consistent with a sequence of independent failures/successes?
We are given the p-values for
$X = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ being $0.002, \quad 0.020, \quad 0.090, \quad 0.254,  \quad0.500, \quad 0.746, \quad 0.910, \quad 0.980 , \quad0.998, \quad 1.000$ respectively.

## My attempts

The amount of changes $K$ are dependent on how many $F's$ are squeezed between two adjacent $S's$.
So for the case where $F$ does not start at the beginning or end,
we require $\frac{K}{2}$ number of failures, where $K$ is even. The number of ways we can do this is: $\begin{pmatrix} n-1 \\ \frac{K}{2}\end{pmatrix}$. Sadly, this is only the case where $K$ is even **and** when the failures are not adjacent to other failures...

$(ii)$ I feel like the most least "consistent" is $(A)$, but I'm not sure how to mathematically reason with this. Do we test a hypothesis that $p = 0.5$ vs. $p \neq 0.5$?

Comment: The probabilities you list are not P-values. They appear to be the CDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(n=9,p=.5).$ In R statistical software `pbinom(0:9, 9, .5)` returns probabilities `0.001953125, 0.019531250, 0.089843750, 0.253906250, 0.500000000, 0.746093750,
 0.910156250, 0.980468750, 0.998046875, 1.000000000`

Comment: Yep, they put it through R as well, (the pbinom(0:9,0,0.5) part), but they confusingly referenced to it as p-values :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might mean which *sequence,* (A), (B), or (C), is least
consistent with independence.

If I count correctly, (A) has 3 changes, (B) has 7 changes, and (C) has 5
changes. For $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(9, .5),$ the expected number is
$E(X) = 4.5.$ So (B), with $X = 7$ is apparently farthest away for
what is expected; that is $|7 - 4.5| = 2.5.$

By the standard definition of P-value,
values of $X$ that are farther away (in either direction) are 0, 1, 2, 7, 8, and 9. So the P-value is $1 - P(X = 3,4,5,6) \approx .18.$ Because this exceeds 0.05,
$X = 7$ is not significantly different from 4.5, so there is not evidence
to argue that even sequence (B) is non-random. This is not surprising because a sequence of ten outcomes is seldom enough to establish non-randomness.

In general, this kind of test of independence is called a *runs test*. You
can google that if you want to know more. (A *run* is a sequence of repeated
values.)

While I have been typing this, another Answer by @spaceisdarkgreen has appeared.
It is somewhat different from mine in details, but I agree with it and have
up-voted it.

Comment: Thanks!  Yep, I think the subsequent parts also refer to it as a runs test.
I'm not sure if I'm misinterpreting when you find your p-values.  
The definition that was given to us is that it is $\mathbb{P}(T(X) > T(x))$ where $T(X)$ is the test statistic (known distribution), and $T(x)$ is the sampled test statistic.  
Is what you did with probability the same as the definition I gave?

Comment: CDF of $X$ is $F_X(t) = P(X \le t),$ which is how I found CDF in my Comment. // P-value is probability (under $H_0$) of result more extreme [in direction(s) of alternative] than value observed, which is how I found the P-value in my Answer. I interpreted alternative hypothesis as 2-sided, so computed values of 0,1,2 on one side and 7,8,9 on the other.

Answer (score 2):

If the coin is fair the probability of a change is 50-50 each time you flip a new coin and is independent of the previous flips. There are $n-1$ opportunities for a change in $n$ flips. This is why it's binomial(1/2,n-1).

To figure out which is least consistent count the number of changes in each data set. You expect $(n-1)/2$ changes and the set that deviates the most from this is the least consistent.

I do not know why they call the list of numbers they give you "p values". It differs sharply from the usual meaning of the term.

Comment: Thank you, that coin example made it much more clear.